# Solving nonlinear (quasi-linear) differential equation by finite difference

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, partial-differential-equations

I have this quasi-linear differential equation:

$u_x+uu_{x}+u_{xx}+u_{xxx}=f(x, u)$

The problem is I don't know how to deal with the non-linear term "$uu_{x}$".
I've try to do this:

$u_x + 0.5(u^2)_x + u_{xx}+u_{xxx}=f(x,u)$

and discrete it

$\frac{1}{2h}(U_{j+1}-U_{j-1}) + \frac{0.5}{2h}(U^2_{j+1}-U^2_{j-1}) + \frac{1}{h^2}(U_{j+1}-2U_j+U_{j-1}) + \frac{1}{2h^3}(U_{j+2}-2U_{j+1}+2U_{j-1}-U_{j-2})=F_j$

but it seems that it can not write in matrix form (as in the linear case) because of the square term?
Or I just discrete the original equation directly:

$\frac{1}{2h}(U_{j+1}-U_{j-1}) + \frac{1}{2h}U_j(U_{j+1}-U_{j-1}) + \frac{1}{h^2}(U_{j+1}-2U_j+U_{j-1}) + \frac{1}{2h^3}(U_{j+2}-2U_{j+1}+2U_{j-1}-U_{j-2})=F_j$

Still can not write in matrix form again.
If someone suggest me some ideas it would be very grateful. Thanks!

---

Follow the comment of @mattos, this is my solution:
First let $v=u_x$ and $t=v_x=u_{xx}$, so the original equation become a ode system:

$(1) v + uv + t + t_x = f(x, u)$
$(2) u_x=v$
$(3) v_x=t$

And let $w=[u, v, t]^T $, then the system of ode can be expressed as:

$(4) w_x = g(w, x)$, where $g(w, x) = [v, t, f(x,u)-t-v-uv]^T$

Then $g(w, x)$ can be divided into two term: Linear term $g_L(w,x)$ and non linear term $g_N(w, x)$:

$(5) g(w,x) = g_L(w,x) + g_N(w,x) = [v, t, t-v]^T + [0, 0, f(x,u)-uv]^T$

Also the linear term can be expressed as a matrix A product w:

$
(6) g_L(w,x) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u \\
v \\
t
\end{pmatrix}
=Aw
$

So using implicit method for linear term and explicit method to non linear term to discrete the equation (4):

$(7) \frac{W_{j+1}-W_j}{h} = AW_{j+1} + g_N(W_j, X_j)$

Then I obtained:

$(8) W_{j+1} = (I-hA)^{-1}(W_j + h \cdot g_N(W_j, X_j))$

So I can solve $W_{j+1}$ explicitly.

My question is, I suddenly found that I can just use eq(4) to discrete into difference form and solve the equation, it is just a simple system ODE problem. Like this:

$W_{j+1} = W_j + h \cdot g(W_j,X_j)$

So what is the advantage of using IMEX to split $g(w,x)$ into linear and nonlinear form to solve? Does it for stability or accuracy?

Comment: Try using an _implicit_ scheme on the linear terms and an _explicit_ scheme on the nonlinear terms, also known as an IMEX (implicit-explicit) approach. This will leave you with a _linear_ algebraic problem in the leading variable $U_{j+1}$. I gave an answer discussing the method [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2731339/implicit-and-explicit-ode/2731927#2731927).

Comment: Thanks! I’ve seen your discussion in that post, but I was wondering if I can write my equation in the form $u_x=L(u,x)+N(u,x)$. The high order differential term make it difficult. Can you give more example? Thank you!

Comment: To do that, you would need to write your ODE as a [first order system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Reduction_to_a_first-order_system) before you applied any numerical scheme. This is usually a better approach than discretising the full ODE directly (I think, though I may be remembering wrong) as it provides better stability properties.

Comment: However, you can just use the discretisation you have in your problem, except make the replacement $$U_{j+1}^{2} - U_{j-1}^{2} \to U_{j}^{2} - U_{j-2}^{2}$$ Here, I am ignoring any stability issues etc that might arise. Now you can write the problem in matrix form as $$\boldsymbol{U}_{j+1} = M(\boldsymbol{U}_{j},\boldsymbol{U}_{j-1},\boldsymbol{U}_{j-2}) + N(\boldsymbol{U}_{j}, \boldsymbol{U}_{j-2})$$ where $N$ is just a vector with the nonlinear terms.

Comment: Thank for your help, very helpful! I will try these methods and add comments if I meet another question. Thanks!

Comment: @mattos Hi I successfully found a solution and I updated the procedure in the content, very thankful! But I have another question that I suddenly found that I can just simply convert the original equation into a system of ODE and solve directly. What is the advantage of using IMEX to split the function into linear term and nonlinear term?

Comment: As I said, using an IMEX scheme (nonlinear terms done explicitly) will yield a _linear_ algebraic problem in the leading variable $U_{j+1}$, so solving for $U_{j+1}$ is easy. If you use an implicit scheme on a nonlinear term, you end up with a _nonlinear_ algebraic problem in the leading variable $U_{j+1}$, which requires root finding methods or something else to solve. Consider $$y'=y^{2}$$ If done explicitly, you get $$y_{n+1}=y_{n}+hy_{n}^{2}$$ which is linear in $y_{n+1}$. Then consider discretising implicitly $$y_{n+1}=y_{n}+hy_{n+1}^{2}$$ Is the last problem easy to solve?

Comment: Sorry that I have not fully understand it well. But if I just use Euler to discrete the eq(4), I can also get a linear algebraic problem in the leading variable: $W_{j+1}  = W_j + h\cdot g(W_j, X_j)$, where $g$ is a nonlinear function. In IMEX method, I need to split $g$ into linear term and nonlinear term before using Euler to discrete $w_x$. But I still can not understand the advantage of IMEX over directly using Euler to discrete $g(w, x)$, cause the latter method can also get a linear leading variable.

Comment: Short answer: implicit schemes are much more robust than explicit, can reasonably solve certain problems that would be prohibitive for an explicit scheme and generally have better accuracy, convergence etc. Google 'advantages of implicit over explicit schemes' or get a book; I would suggest the books by [Hairer and Wanner](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=IeKnXruYBPGd4-EPi-a-8AY&q=hairer+wanner+solving+ordinary+differential+equations&oq=hairer+wanner+solving&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgYIABAWEB46AggAUOwXWJAeYLcmaABwAHgAgAH0AYgBtQ-SAQUwLjYuNJgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab)

Comment: I understand, thank you very much!