# Help understanding how to apply IMEX methods to one-dimensional PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, linear-pde

I need to compute a solution of the following PDE:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + v \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$$

For didactic purposes, I need to use an IMEX method. The point is no one ever illustrated such methods to me, so I did some research on the web and on chatgpt and I got to some conclusions. I am here to ask if my reasoning is correct and if not (as it probably is) what I'm doing wrong.

What I learned is

1. Take your PDE and solve one of the two derivatives explicitly. For this I can use, for instance, [Heun's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heun%27s_method). What I obtain is

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + v \frac{u_{ex}^{n+1} - u^n}{\Delta x} = 0$$

where $u_{ex}^{n+1}$ is the solution of Heun's method, i.e. the explicit step.

2. Use your new explicit solution to resolve implicitly the other derivative. In other words, use [Backward Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_Euler_method) (for instance) to resolve

$$\frac{u^{n+1}-u_{ex}^{n+1}}{\Delta t} + v \frac{u^{n+1}-u_{ex}^{n+1}}{\Delta x} = 0$$

where $u^{n+1}$ is the solution of the implicit method and of the whole time step.

3. Iterate.

Is the reasoning right? I already don't think so because if I develop the last equation I get

\begin{align}
\Delta x \cdot (u^{n+1}-u_{ex}^{n+1}) &= -v \Delta t \cdot (u^{n+1}-u_{ex}^{n+1}) \\ 
u^{n+1}(v\Delta t + \Delta x) &= u_{ex}^{n+1}(v\Delta t + \Delta x) \\ 
u^{n+1} &= u_{ex}^{n+1}
\end{align}

which makes the implicit step useless.

So please, what's that I couldn't get right? It's ok even if you only point a book or a text where to learn.

EDIT:

As [Matthew Cassell](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/181563/matthew-cassell) replied, I used the same discretisation both for time and space. Dividing the two different discretisations on the index $n$ for time and $k$ for space, I get

$$\frac{u_{k+1}^{n+1}-u_{k+1}^n}{\Delta t}+v\frac{u_{k+1}^n-u_k^n}{\Delta x}=0$$

where I first derived on $k$ (space) with the Heun's method (explicit) and then on $n$ (time) using Backward Euler (implicit). But now two more doubts arise:

1. In the last equation, everything but $u_{k+1}^{n+1}$ is known, so I can easily develop the equation and get to
   $$u_{k+1}^{n+1}=u_{k+1}^n-v\Delta t\frac{u_{k+1}^n-u_k^n}{\Delta x}$$
   So where's the implicit step? I expected an equation less trivial, in which something of uncertain nonsingularity would end at denominator; but I guess that since my implicit term $\left(\frac{\delta u}{\delta t}\right)$ is linear i don't get that. Good!
2. In this way, I get $u_{k+1}^{n+1}$, which is the value at the next time step, but also at the next space step. Isn't it a problem that my solution moves forward in space, if I have no periodic boundary condition? In other words, how do I get $u_k^{n+1}$? But do I really need $u_k^{n+1}$?

Comment: What exactly is IMEX?

Comment: @K.defaoite Discretisations that apply both IMplicit and EXplicit methods simultaneously.

Comment: In your example you have discretised the spatial and temporal derivatives using the same indexing, with a superscript $n$, which doesn't make sense. For example, a forward Euler in time ($n$), backward Euler in space ($k$) so that $u^{n}_{k} = u(x_{k}, t_{n})$ gives $$\frac{u^{n + 1}_{k+1} - u^{n}_{k + 1}}{\Delta t} = \frac{u^{n}_{k+1} - u^{n}_{k}}{\Delta t}$$

Comment: Lastly, I've given answers on IMEX methods [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2731339/implicit-and-explicit-ode/2731927#2731927) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2960358/forward-euler-pde-grid-method-misunderstanding-is-the-question-missing-a-det/2960477#2960477). Hopefully they give you what you're after.

Comment: To answer your questions in the edit 1. I'm not sure what you mean by 'implicit step'; you've discretised your spatial derivative implicitly (backward Euler) and the temporal derivative explicitly (forward Euler). I also don't understand what you mean by 'something of uncertain nonsingularity would end at denominator', though it seems you understand why there are no issues in this particular problem.

Comment: 2. You need $u^{n + 1}_{k + 1}$ **for all $k = 0, \dots, K$** where $K$ is the number of spatial points. This means that at each time step, we are solving for the entire vector $$(u^{n+1}_{1}, u^{n+1}_{2}, \dots, u^{n+1}_{k}, u^{n+1}_{k+1}, \dots u^{n+1}_{K})^{T}$$ which includes the $u^{n+1}_{k}$ term. You can always reindex $k + 1 \to k$ if you want. Also, to answer your question 'isn't it a problem that my solution moves forward in space', think about what your PDE actually represents. In turn, consider what happens if you take $v, \Delta t, \Delta x$ such that $v \Delta t / \Delta x = 1$.

Comment: You are understanding IMEX methods wrong. IMEX refers only to the time discretization. Once a spatial discretization has been chosen, IMEX works by time-stepping some terms with an implicit scheme and others with an explicit scheme in some consistent fashion so that convergence of the method is preserved.

Comment: @MatthewCassell by 'implicit step' i mean the second step in the procedure: after i explicitly discretise the spatial derivative $\delta u / \delta x$ and find $u_{k+1}^n$ by Heun's method, the next step is the implicit discretisation of the temporal derivative $\delta u / \delta t$ with which i find $u_{k+1}^{n+1}$ by backward Euler. What i didn't expect was to find such a simple formula for $u_{k+1}^{n+1}$: usually when i use any implicit scheme, i find myself in need of reversing a matrix (which hence must be non singular) or something alike in order to find $u_{k+1}^{n+1}$.

Comment: @MatthewCassell my PDE actually represents how the variation in time of $u$ is linked to its variation in space, right? So of course my solution is moving, but i was unsure about who or what grants me that i can reindex $k+1\rightarrow k$, or if i need to. Is it what i should do or it's some sort of unallowed manipulation of the solution?

Comment: @whpowell96 so you're saying that IMEX methods are for ODE only? Would you mind elaborate a bit on the argument, please?

Comment: @EleDan You don't get that issue in the example I gave because we used an explicit method in time, not implicit. The reindexing is just a relabelling; let $k + 1 := j$ if you want. IMEX methods can be used for ODEs and PDEs, its just that IMEX methods are applied to the *temporal derivative only* as whpowell96 stated. In the example in my comment above we haven't used an IMEX scheme, only an explicit scheme (forward Euler). Taking these points together, perhaps you should get a handle on basic discretisations of ODEs and PDEs first, then look at IMEX schemes later.

Comment: Yes, IMEX methods are for ODEs only. However, performing some sort of spatial discretization transforms PDEs into ODEs, which can then be solved in this manner. This is often used for advection-diffusion equations where the advection terms is handled explicitly and the diffusion term is handled implicitly.

Comment: MatthewCassell and whpowell96 thank you both for helping me! I'm going to delve better in discretisation first and then i'll decide what to do with IMEX schemes...

Comment: Maybe start with [this book by Langtangen](https://hplgit.github.io/prog4comp/doc/pub/p4c_Python.pdf) (chapters 4 and 5, unless you want to practice programming in Python as well) and then [this second book by Langtangen](https://hplgit.github.io/fdm-book/doc/pub/book/pdf/fdm-book-4print.pdf).

Comment: Thank you so muche for the books suggestions @MatthewCassell